# Finding $a$ such that a product of iid $U(0,a)$ converges to $0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $a > 0$, let $X_n$, $n \geq 1$, be iid random variables that are uniform on $(0,a)$, and let $Y_n = \prod_{k=1}^n X_k$. Determine, with a proof, all values of $a$ for which $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Y_n=0$ with probability one.

By using Markov and Borel-Cantelli, I showed that if $a<2$, then $P\left(\lim_n Y_n = 0\right) = 1$.

Then, I argued (incorrectly) that if $a \geq 2$, then $\mathbb{E}X_k \geq 1$, which implies that $\mathbb{E}Y_n \geq 1$ for all $n$. But then, if $\lim_n Y_n = 0$ almost surely, then $\mathbb{E}\left(\lim_n Y_n \right) = 0$, and so, $a$ cannot be greater than 2.

Where did I make my mistake? Is it that $\mathbb{E} (\lim_n Y_n) \neq \lim_n \mathbb{E}Y_n$?

Also, apparently, the answer is $e$, which is found by considering $\log Y_n$ and using the Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: You gave all the explanations, what is left to do?

Comment: @Did I just wanted to verify that that was where I made my mistake. Would $n 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ be a sufficient counterexample?